# Turn play on a wet board with top-top, flush and straight draw

Tags: poker-strategy

Cash game (2/2€), 9-players, lots of players limp / call any raise pre-flop. Lots of hands involve 4, 5 or even 6 players after the flop. Been pretty much card dead for the last hour.

Due to the loose nature of the game I don't get involved much, bluffing is useless. Was stuck a bit, but the hand before this I doubled up with KK. My stack is 230$.

Hand after the double up I get A♠K♠ in MP. Two players in EP limp. Pot is 8€, I raise to 20€. One of the loose players after me calls. I've noticed he calls pre-flop and on the flop a lot, but often releases his hand on the turn. One of the limpers also calls, second limper folds. The limper that called is tighter, if he misses the flop he usually folds.

Pot: 66€. Flop comes K:diamonds:7:spades:Q:hearts:. I flop top pair, top kicker with a backdoor flush draw. It checks to me and I bet 40€, player behind me calls and the player in early position folds. Pot is now 146€.

Turn is the J:spades: giving me the nut flush draw and a gut shot to a straight. I have 170€ left which is slightly more than the pot. If I check I don't see myself folding if he bets, any reasonably sized bet on his part will commit me. I shove...he thinks for 10 seconds and calls somewhat unsure.

River is a brick and he turns over K7 off suit for a flopped two pair. Don't know if I should like my turn play here, don't like to overcommit with top pair, top kicker generally. He could easily have KQ, KJ, 77, QJ, AT (somewhat less likely)...don't think I'm getting called by worse often.

Any opinions are appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think you played it OK.

K7 and Q7 seem pretty loose to me but if you are going to put K7 in his range then need to include Q7.  And put AK in his range.

KK, QQ, and JJ should raise pre flop

You are only behind KQ, KJ, QJ, K7, Q7, AT, and 77. Against two pair you pick up outs. Against K7 you have 3 aces, 9 spades, 2 queens, and 3 tens = 17. Against that hand you were getting odds to call if you check he pushed.  You were almost getting proper odds to call KQ.

Not sure pushing was good on the turn as any worse hand is going to fold out. AK is basically the bottom of your range. I think you should call if you check and he pushes the turn because there are bluffs and weaker draws in his range. If he checks back the turn and a blank hits the river then you have a chance to get away.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Good point on check calling the turn, as you mention, as least that keeps bluffs and weaker draws in his range.